# ls -l --group-directories-first (act on symlinks as well)

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, ls, symlink

`ls` option `--group-directories-first` causes directories to be listed on the top, which makes the output of `ls` nice and clean:

```
ls -l --group-directories-first
```

However, it does not act on `symlinks`, which are actually `symlinks` to directories. There is a possibility to use

```
ls -l -L --group-directories-first
```

which will list both kind of directories on top, but will not distinguish between proper directory and symlinked directory, which is again confusing.

Can `ls` display symlinked directories on top, while still keeping them distinct from regular directories?

**EDIT:**
I am using `bash`.

Comment: This is idiosyncratic behaviour on the part of `ls`. According to the `stat()` system call, a symbolic link to a directory is still a directory (`S_ISDIR(st_mode)` will return true).  Evidentially `ls` discounts the symlinks  *before* it checks this.

Comment: @goldilocks, no, `ls` does `lstat()` (and `readlink` for symlinks) unless you use the `-L` option (in which case it uses `stat()`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Hmm, live and learn.  I had thought that `S_ISLNK(st_mode)` also returned true via `stat()`, but it doesn't -- it only does so via `lstat()`.  Also that ISLNK doesn't return true via stat even if the link is a link to a link.  Meaning that `ISLNK` might never returns true via stat, although that's kind of unspecified...

Comment: @goldilocks, `stat` gives you the properties of the file at the end of the symlink(s). If that doesn't exist or is not accessible, the `stat` returns a ENOENT, so what is returned by `stat` will never be a symlink. `stat()` will never tell you anything about symlinks, just like `open` will never open the symlink, or `chmod()` will not change the permissions of a symlink... etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but if using `zsh`, you could do:

```
mll() {
  (($#)) || set -- *(N-/) *(N^-/)
  (($#)) && ls -ldU -- $@
}
```

You could also define a globbing sort order like:

```
dir1st() { [[ -d $REPLY ]] && REPLY=1-$REPLY || REPLY=2-$REPLY;}
```

and use it like:

```
ls -ldU -- *(o+dir1st)
```

That  way, you can use it for other commands than `ls` or with `ls` with different options, or for different patterns like:

```
ls -ldU -- .*(o+dir1st) # to list the hidden files and dirs
```

or:

```
ls -ldU -- ^*[[:lower:]]*(o+dir1st) # to list the all-uppercase files and dirs
```

If you have to use `bash`, the equivalent would be like:

```
mll() (
  if (($# == 0)); then
    dirs=() others=()
    shopt -s nullglob
    for f in *; do
      if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        dirs+=("$f")
      else
        others+=("$f")
      fi
    done
    set -- "${dirs[@]}" "${others[@]}"
  fi
  (($#)) && exec ls -ldU -- "$@"
)
```

`bash` doesn't have globbing qualifiers or any way to affect the sort order of globs, or any way to turn nullglob on a per-glob basis, or have local context for options (other than starting a subshell, hence the `()` instead of `{}` above) AFAIK.

Comment: Is there any similar trick for `bash` ?