# How to use ls to group directory symlinks with other directories?

Tags: files, ls, symlink

`ls --group-directories-first` displays all directories before files, but if there is a symlink to a directory, it is displayed among the files. Is there a way to group directory-symlinks with other regular directories?

Comment: Does `-L` do what you want?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Well, not exactly. This way I don't recognise if it's a symlink or not. But still, the best solution so far - you should make it an answer.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111637/ls-l-group-directories-first-act-on-symlinks-as-well. A solution in the accepted answer works well for me in `bash`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `-L`. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users    0 Dec 20 13:23 A
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja users 4096 Dec 20 13:23 b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja users    1 Dec 20 13:23 sl -> b
$ ls --group-directories-first -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja users 4096 Dec 20 13:23 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users    0 Dec 20 13:23 A
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja users    1 Dec 20 13:23 sl -> b
$ ls --group-directories-first -lL
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja users 4096 Dec 20 13:23 b
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja users 4096 Dec 20 13:23 sl
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users    0 Dec 20 13:23 A
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that's possible without `-L` (which gives you information on the target of the symlink instead of the symlink).

you could always run `two` ls invocations, one for the directories, one for the non-directories. With `zsh`:

```
lldirfirst() {
  local -a dir nondir
  local ret=0
  dir=(*(N-/)) nondir=(*(N^-/))
  (($#dir == 0)) || ls -ld -- $dir || ret=$?
  (($#nondir == 0)) || ls -ld -- $nondir || ret=$?
  return $ret
}
```

That's for `ls -l` in the current directory only, it would need to be adapted to list other files/dirs.

Also beware column alignment may get broken:

```
$ lldirfirst
drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 4096 Dec 20 13:20 c
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas    1 Dec 20 13:20 d -> c
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 Dec 20 13:20 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 0 Dec 20 13:20 b
```

Another option would be to use `-qF` and sort the lines that end in `/` first (assumes GNU `ls` as not all `ls` implementation will put a `/` there for symlinks to directories, and a `sort` implementation that supports `-s` like GNU `sort`, but your `--group-directories-first` is GNU specific already anyway):

```
lsdirfirst() {
  ls -qF "$@" |
    awk '{if(/^total [0-9]+$/ || /\/$/) n=1; else n=2; print n, $0}' |
    sort -sk1,1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
}
```

Example:

```
$ lsdirfirst -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 chazelas chazelas 4096 Dec 20 13:20 c/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas    1 Dec 20 13:20 d -> c/
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas    0 Dec 20 13:20 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas    0 Dec 20 13:20 b
```

Note that with `zsh`, you can tell its completion system to list the directories first with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-dirs-first true
```

And it does put symlinks to directories in the *directory* category:

```
$ ls Tab
Completing directory
c/  d@
Completing files
a   b
```

(with colors and those *Completing...* descriptions if enabled with more `zstyle`s)

You can enable that completion style on a per-command basic by changing that `zstyle` command to:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:(ls|echo):*:*' list-dirs-first true
```

for instance to enable it only for the `ls` and `echo` commands.

Here's an example of `~/.zshrc` configuration to get that output in color above.

```
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate _prefix
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-dirs-first true
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -i
```

See also the `compinstall` function for a menu-based interface to configure zsh completion.

Comment: IIUC, `mll` presented here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111639/72304 would do what OP wants in `bash`, right?

Comment: If anyone uses the `lsdirfirst()` function and wants to use the human-readable `-h` option, modify the regex to read `/^total [0-9\.]+\w+?$/`. Without this, the "total" will display between the directories and files, which is not where it should display.