# ls output: group directory symlinks with directories

Tags: linux, ls, coreutils

Using the `--group-directories-first` option I can group the ls output as follows:

```
[a-z directories] [a-z files and symlinks]
```

However, I would like symlinked directories to appear with the rest of the directories, like this:

```
[a-z directories and symlinked directories] [a-z files and symlinked files]
```

Using the `-L` (dereference) option gets me half way there. Symlinked directories are sorted the way I want, but they appear just as normal directories, the information that they are symlinks is lost.

Is there any way to group directories and symlinked directories first, while still preserving the colour coding showing which directories are symlinks?

Comment: Previously: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232394/86440, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111637/86440, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412018/86440 (I’m not suggesting this is a duplicate; these provide additional context).

Comment: Interesting. Can I ask why? I am thinking about what `ls` would have to do to get this behaviour: it would have to call `stat` twice for each file (`stat` and `lstat`). Normally `ls` uses `lstat`, but with `-L` option uses `stat`. Therefore I suspect that `ls` does not support what you are asking for. However it would not be impossible, bit it would be slower.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Because 99% of the time I "use" a symlinked directory I'm treating it as if it was just a normal directory. To me it doesn't make any sense for it to be grouped with the files. Obviously it isn't a normal directory though which is why I would still like it to be highlighted as such.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it already runs stat on the symlink target too if you have `--color` or `-F` set

Comment: @StephenKitt, what makes you say they're not duplicates?

Comment: @JShorthouse Some. But I just don't care that it is a symlink for that 99% of the time.

Comment: What about: `ls -l |sort`

Comment: @schweik Has the exact same effect as `--group-directories-first`. Symlinked directories are listed after the normal directories. I want them all to be sorted together.

Comment: @Stéphane going by the new phrasing around duplicates, “do the answers to this other question answer your question”, and since I reckoned JShorthouse had seen at least some of the other Qs&As, which didn’t provide an answer, then it seemed to be that suggesting them as dupes wasn’t appropriate. (I tread lightly when I’m wielding a hammer.) Then again, [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111639/86440) does seem to answer this question too...